# Safari SSL certificate 403 forbidden

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, ssl, safari

I have a web application deployed onto IIS 7 (Version 7.0.6000) on a Window 2008 Server using an SSL certificate (issued by Equifax). The web application is accessible over https using IE, Firefox and Chrome. However on Safari, I first get a pop up to choose a certificate and upon choosing a valid one, i get the following message:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
```

We have had a slight issue with time on that server where is tends to lag behind by a minute, but I don't think that would ONLY through out SAFARI and not any other browser.

Comment: I think you may be a little mistaken. IIS6 shipped with Server 2003. IIS7 shipped with 2008. Which platform are you actually using, since what you listed can't exist?

Comment: @MarkM: Thanks for pointing that out and sorry about the error. It is IIS 7 actually.

Answer (score 1):

A minute should not be a problem. If I am correct about the underlying problem the big thing is that timezones match up.

Some of my users are located in the Philippines and had Windows 7 systems set up with US time zones. They adjusted the time to be correct but the timezone setting would reliably lock out a couple of their installed browsers. This was especially true with one specific certificate we had. I believe it was an Equifax. Verify the expiration date for the CRL listed on your certificate - if it is within 24 hours of the current time and the timezone is off that is the likely culprit.